# For which rational values of $a$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{5} + a}) / \mathbb{Q}$ a normal extension?

Tags: galois-theory, normal-extension

For which rational values of $a$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{5} + a}) / \mathbb{Q}$ a normal field extension?

My main approach to solving this has been to look at when $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{5} + a})$ is the splitting field of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. I've shown that $\sqrt{\sqrt{5} + a}$ is a root of the polynomial $x^4 -2ax^2 + a^2 -5$, however I'm not sure when $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{5} + a})$ is a splitting field for this polynomial.

Comment: The roots of your polynomial are $\pm\sqrt{a\pm \sqrt{5}}$, so depending on $a$ your field may be real and the splitting field will have non-real elements.

Comment: @i.m.soloveichik it's easy to see that if $a^2 - 5 < 0,$ then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+a}) \subset \mathbb{R}$ cannot contain $\sqrt{-\sqrt{5}+a} \in \mathbb{C}.$ But how can we go further? Can we restrict more values of $a$, or is this the only restriction?

Comment: If $a^2-5$ is a square or $5$*square then the field is normal.  I leave the details to you.